# Dispatch event of product tag save from admin

Tags: product-tag

Is there any dispatch event available for product tag save from admin

I want to do save that tag in my table when its status change pending to approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento, there are ***no dispatch event available*** for ***product tag save from admin***

Only you can do you can achieve by default model events `save_after,save_before,commit_after` etc.

### Events list:

- `tag_save_before`
- `tag_save_after`
- `tag_save_commit_before`
- `tag_save_commit_after`

With specify ***those events for admin area*** by define  event area as `<adminhtml>`.

> ```
> <adminhtml>
> <events>...
> ```

Code;

**Define event at config.**

`<adminhtml> <!-- by define area event only fire when it admin -->
    <events>
        <tag_save_before> <!-- event name -->
            <observers>
                <fire_admin_end_tag_observer>
                    <class>[MOdule_Model_Model_Prefix]/Observer</class>
                    <method>fireAddObserveronadmin</method>
                </fire_admin_end_tag_observer>
            </observers>
        </tag_save_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>`

**Observer  class**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{
{

    public function fireAddObserveronadmin($observer){
        $tag=$observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        .. do whatever
    } 
}
```

Comment: i have one question if i m change status from grid than how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In `config.xml`,

```
<adminhtml> 
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_tag_save>
          <observers>
            <item_save_after>
                <class>Mymodule_Namespace_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>saveBefore</method>
            </item_save_after>
          </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_tag_save>
     </events>
</adminhtml>
```

In `observer.php`,

```
 class Mymodule_Namespace_Model_Observer {

     public function saveBefore($observer){
         $params =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
         /*
           Custom code to save data in your custom table
         */
      }
 }
```